# spark-submit and spark-shell results mismatch

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple test spark program as below, the strange thing is that it runs well under a spark-shell, but will get a runtime error of

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
```

in spark-submit, which indicate the line of:

```
val maps2=maps.collect.toMap
```

has problem. But why the compilation has no problem and it works well under spark-shell? Thanks!

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.HashingTF
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark._
import SparkContext._


val docs=sc.parallelize(Array(Array("once" ,"upon", "a", "time"), Array("there", "was", "a", "king")))

val hashingTF = new HashingTF()

val maps=docs.flatMap{term=>term.map(ele=>(hashingTF.indexOf(ele),ele))}

val maps2=maps.collect.toMap
```

Comment: How does your build.sbt look? I am guessing that you aren't including mllib, which is not included in core spark by default.

Comment: The build file is:   name := "TEST"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem.  The fix was to match my scalaVersion in the sbt to the same version used by spark-shell.  Like you I was specifying a "2.11.x" version in my sbt.  At the time of this writing the spark binaries are compiled against scala 2.10.x.

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
```

To check your spark-shell scala version :

```
scala> scala.util.Properties.versionString
res7: String = version 2.10.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see in which scala version is spark compiled, i had the same problem, sbt was with 2.11.7 and spark was with 2.10. Try it !